# unexpectedly stop in php exec wget procession

Tags: php, exec, wget

I'm running the code to download media from my server, and it seems properly.
After a few loops it runs, it unexpectly stop. After download a large file(almost 1Gb), It stop at the 'echo "66666666"', and doesn't go forward.

I'm running it on linux use 'nohup php -f mycode.php > nohup.out &' to run the code background. And use nohup.out to see what's going on.
First I thought it was the code' problem, but after I try some samll files(hundreds Mb or much samller) it worked properly. So I changed the max_execution_time of php, but it still didn't work on large file.

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($list);$i++)
    {
        if(!($list[$i]['name'] == 'index.html'))
        {
            echo "coming in \n";
            if(pathinfo($list[$i]['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'wmv' || pathinfo($list[$i]['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'mkv' || pathinfo($list[$i]['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'mp4' || pathinfo($list[$i]['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'webm')
            {
                exec("wget 'http://*.*.*.*/".$list[$i]['name']."'");
            }   
            echo "666666666666666666";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got 'INFO: task wget:1064 blocked for more than 120 seconds. "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.'